# Taking the average of multiple sharedpreferences in Android?

Tags: android, math

I am trying to take the average of multiple sharedpreference values in Android, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code that is "suppose" to caluclate the average:

```
if(amountOfMphValues > 1)
{
    for(int i = 0; prefs.getInt(MPH_VALUE + i, 0) != 0; i++)
    {
        averageMphArray.add(prefs.getInt(MPH_VALUE + i, 0));
    }

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = averageMphArray.iterator();
    int averageValue = 0;

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        averageValue = averageValue + iterator.next().intValue();
    }

    if(averageMphArray.size() > 0)
    {
        saveUserPrefs(AVERAGE_MPH, averageValue / averageMphArray.size());
    }
}
```

SOLVED:

Ok, I got it to work.  In the for loop, the i variable needed to start at 1 instead of 0, since my sharedpreferences started at 1.

Fixed version for whoever needs it:

```
for(int i = 1; prefs.getInt(MPH_VALUE + i, 0) != 0; i++)
{
    averageMphArray.add(prefs.getInt(MPH_VALUE + i, 0));
}
```

Comment: What's the result?  Why is the result wrong?  Is it missing values, finding no values, etc?  In addition-  why are you using shared preferences for this kind of data?  It just isn't meant for it.  Write the data to a file, please.

Comment: @GabeSechan Either the result is nothing or it's 0.  Overall, it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like you either don't have data in your shared preferences or you're using the wrong key(s).  The averaging code looks ok, if its somewhat awkwardly written.

Comment: If your problem is solved, I would recommend writing your solution as an answer to the question. This will make it easier for other users with similar problems to find the solution.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't allow me because I'm too "new".